# Theme Toggler not persisting through refresh despite localStorage use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, themes

Doing a theme toggler for a project which works perfectly if not refreshed. Here is the code:

```
 const initialTheme = () => window.localStorage.getItem('theme') || true;
    const [lightTheme, setLightTheme] = useState(initialTheme);
    const { body } = document;

    useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', lightTheme);

        lightTheme === true
            ? body.parentElement.dataset.theme = 'light'
            : body.parentElement.dataset.theme = 'dark'
    }, [lightTheme])
```

So when the toggle is applied, the data-theme on the html tag is set to either light or dark.
However, when I refresh, the page goes back to the dark theme no matter what. I have no data-theme on the html tag, I do that dynamically with the code above.

The weird part is that the value in the localStorage is always correct. When I make it light theme, the localStorage value is true - which it's supposed to be - and when dark theme the value is false(correct again). This localStorage value persists through refreshing.

Please help if you can & thanks!

Comment: while initializing `lightTheme` you are just passing the function the function body in `useState`. You have to call that function in order to evaluate the value and pass in `useState` like this, `const [lightTheme, setLightTheme] = useState(initialTheme());`

Answer (score 1):

When you get your data back from localStorage, you get either the string value `"true"` or the string value `"false"`. Therefore, the value of lightTheme never evaluates to `true` and your code always renders the second part of your ternary operator, which is the dark theme. Try persisting `'light'` or `'dark'`in localStorage instead and toggling based on those values.